# Bitwise OR to define SqlBulkCopyOptions?

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, bitwise-or

So I asked one of my senior Dev for help to figure out Transaction scope related problem and he came to my desk and used a different overload on SqlBulkCopy and for SqlBulkCopyOptions parameter he did something like below:

```
SqlBulkCopyOptions options = (SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints);
```

It works now, but I don't get what a `bitwise or` means here. I thought I had some understanding of it, never really used it, but this usage made me scratch my head. Yep, I didn't ask my senior to explain it to me.. I was hoping someone could help me understand what the statement does. Most of the bitwise or examples on the net are with some numbers, which I get (I think), but this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An enum can be used as a flag if it has the `[Flags]` attribute and has enum values which are independent of each other:

The definition of `SqlBulkCopyOptions` is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopyOptions.cs

Ignore the use of bitshift syntax. The actual values are:

```
Name              Hex  Dec  Pow 2   Binary
Default          =  0 =  0 =    0 = 00000000
KeepIdentity     =  1 =  1 =    1 = 00000001
CheckConstraints =  2 =  2 =    2 = 00000010
TableLock        =  4 =  4 =    3 = 00000100
KeepNulls        =  8 =  8 =    4 = 00001000
FireTriggers     = 10 = 16 =    5 = 00010000
UseInternalTxn   = 20 = 32 =    6 = 00100000
```

Observe that each value is the next power of 2, which means in binary (last column) their bits are completely mutually exclusive.

This means you can combine them in a way that lets you see each value is set, for example, if you want `KeepIdentity` and `TableLock`, that's `0x01` with `0x04`. We use the OR operator, but on a per-bit basis, which gives us the behaviour we want:

In binary:

```
00000001
00000100 OR
--------
00000101
```

Observe how the first and third bits are now `1`.

Thus, (`KeepIdentity | TableLock == 5`).

This approach does not work for enum values which are not powers of two, for example, if `KeepIdentity` had a value of `1` and `CheckConstraints` had a value of `2` but `TableLock` had a value of `3`, then in binary they are:

```
00000001 KeepIdentity
00000010 CheckConstraints
00000011 TableLock
```

Observe that by analysing the bits of `00000011` it is impossible to determine if this is the combination of `KeepIdentity` and `CheckConstraints`, or a single `TableLock` value. This is why flags enum values must be: 1. Powers of 2, and 2: mutually-exclusive (with exceptions for shorthand and combination values).

Answer (score 1):

The principle is exactly the same with an `enum` as it is with numbers, as the underlying type of an `enum` is always an integral type. If you look at the [declaration](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopyOptions.cs,7ecbb90c58a9f11a) of `SqlBulkCopyOptions`, you'll see that its members have underlying values that are powers of two so that they can be combined in this way.

Comment: I hate to say that I wasn't aware of that link you posted until this post. That's a great resource! Thanks.